# How to send an e.parameter to Google Apps Script using PHP and cURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl, google-apps-script

The code below works. It sends data to a google apps script using the `e.queryString` request parameter. I'd like to know how to update it so it sends the same data, but using an object and the `e.parameter` parameter instead.

How would I update my working code so it sends the following object `e.parameter` to my script @ `https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXSCRIPTIDXXXXX/exec` and returns the values to my php file?

**Object**

```
{"responderName": "todd", "presenterName": "steve"}
```

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

**Working PHP Code using `e.queryString` parameter**

```
$url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXSCRIPTIDXXXXX/exec?responderName=todd&presenterName=steve';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
curl_close($curl);
```

**Working Apps Script Code using `e.queryString`**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(params);
}
```

Comment: Unclear. Your want to send a object instead of sending a query string?

Comment: @TheMaster, I'm sorry the question wasn't worded correctly. The answer is use. I want to send an object instead of a querystring. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The event object already has a `parameter` and a `parameters` property. Google constructs the object received in your `doGet` method from the  URL parameters https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters Take a look at e in your Stackdriver logging after adding this snippet: `console.log({ message: "doget e", eventObject: e })`

Comment: @tehhowch, thank you. This info helped me understand that my question is worded wrong. I'm trying to figure out how-to send the info to Google Apps Script with out using a query-string in the URL. Is it possible to send the object without adding the data to the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to send the data of `responderName=todd&presenterName=steve` to Web Apps without using the URL query parameter.
- Your Web Apps has been deployed as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`.
- You want to send the data using the curl of PHP.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

When you want to send the data to Web Apps without using the URL query parameter, it is required to use the POST method. So in your case, please use `doPost()` instead of `doGet()`. By this, the data can be received as the POST method.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script:

Please modify your Google Apps Script as follows.

```
function doPost(e) { // Modified
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(params);
}
```

- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected. Please be careful this.

#### PHP:

Please modify your PHP script as follows.

```
$data = array(
    'responderName' => 'todd',
    'presenterName' => 'steve'
);

$url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$header = ['Content-Type: application/json'];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
curl_close($curl);
```

- In this case, the headers might not be required to be used.

#### Result:

When above PHP script is used, the following event object can be retrieved at `e` of `doPost(e)`. In this case, the data can be retrieved by `e.postData.contents`. But in this case, if you want to use the data as JSON object, please use `JSON.parse()`.

```
{
  "parameter": {},
  "contextPath": "",
  "contentLength": 48,
  "queryString": "",
  "parameters": {},
  "postData": {
    "type": "application/json",
    "length": 48,
    "contents": "{\"responderName\":\"todd\",\"presenterName\":\"steve\"}",
    "name": "postData"
  }
}
```

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Mr. B Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: You've helped me several times on here, I really appreciate you! Have a great week.